# How to stop nulls from sqoop import (oracle to hive)

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am getting null rows in hive after sqoop import from oracle to hive

in sqoop --query, I mentioned where pk is not null .

sqoop query :

```
sqoop import \
--connect "${SQOOP_CONN_STR}" \
--connection-manager "${SQOOP_CONNECTION_MANAGER}" \
--username ${SQOOP_USER} \
--password ${SQOOP_PASSWORD} \
--fields-terminated-by ${SQOOP_DELIM} \
--null-string '' \
--null-non-string '' \
--query \""${SQOOP_QUERY}"\" \
--target-dir "${SQOOP_OP_DIR}" \
--split-by ${SQOOP_SPLIT_BY} \
-m ${SQOOP_NUM_OF_MAPPERS} 1> ${SQOOP_TEMP_LOG}
```

Comment: you want to filter null rows or column ?Plz provide your sqoop command

Comment: sqoop import --connect "${SQOOP_CONN_STR}" --connection-manager "${SQOOP_CONNECTION_MANAGER}" 
--username ${SQOOP_USER} --password ${SQOOP_PASSWORD} --fields-terminated-by ${SQOOP_DELIM} --null-string '' 
--null-non-string '' --query \""${SQOOP_QUERY}"\"  --target-dir "${SQOOP_OP_DIR}" --split-by ${SQOOP_SPLIT_BY} 
-m ${SQOOP_NUM_OF_MAPPERS} 1> ${SQOOP_TEMP_LOG}

Comment: Import command is correct. Are you getting `null` during Hive query ?

Answer (score 0):

**It is due to change in field delimiter.**

You are importing in HDFS without specifying any field delimiter. So, it will use default comma.

Hive table you created might have `CTRL^A`*(default)* as field delimiter.

Make these in sync, it should work.